# In PostgreSQL, conditionally count rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Background**

I'm a novice Postgres user running a local server on a Windows 10 machine. I've got a dataset `g` that looks like this:

```
+--+---------+----------------+
|id|treatment|outcome_category|
+--+---------+----------------+
|a |1        |cardiovascular  |
|a |0        |cardiovascular  |
|b |0        |metabolic       |
|b |0        |sensory         |
|c |1        |NULL            |
|c |0        |cardiovascular  |
|c |1        |sensory         |
|d |1        |NULL             |
|d |0        |cns            |
+--+---------+----------------+
```

**The Problem**

I'd like to get a count of `outcome_category` by `outcome_category` for those `id` who are "ever treated" -- defined as "`id`'s who have any row where `treatment`=1".

Here's the desired result:

```
+----------------+---------+
|outcome_category|  count  |
+----------------+---------+
|cardiovascular  |    3    |
|sensory         |    1    |
|cns             |    1    |
+----------------+---------+
```

It would be fine if the result had to contain `metabolic`, like so:

```
+----------------+---------+
|outcome_category|treatment|
+----------------+---------+
|cardiovascular  |    3    |
|metabolic       |    0    |
|sensory         |    1    |
|cns             |    1    |
+----------------+---------+
```

Obviously I don't need the rows to be in any particular order, though descending would be nice.

**What I've tried**

Here's a query I've written:

```
select treatment, outcome_category, sum(outcome_ct)
from (select max(treatment) as treatment,
    outcome_category,
    count(outcome_category) as outcome_ct
    from g
    group by outcome_category) as sub
group by outcome_category, sub.treatment;
```

But it's a mishmash result:

```
+---------+----------------+---+
|treatment|outcome_category|sum|
+---------+----------------+---+
|1        |cardiovascular  |3  |
|1        |sensory         |2  |
|0        |metabolic       |1  |
|1        |NULL            |0  |
|0        |cns             |1  |
+---------+----------------+---+
```

I'm trying to identify the "ever exposed" `id`'s using that first line in the subquery: `select max(treatment) as treatment`. But I'm not quite getting at the rest of it.

**EDIT**

I realized that the toy dataset `g` I originally gave you above doesn't correspond to the idiosyncrasies of my real dataset. I've updated `g` to reflect that many `id`'s who are "ever treated" won't have a non-null `outcome_category` next to a row with `treatment`=1.

Comment: Why is "cns" counted? It has only a zero value...

Comment: Great question. It's counted because the `id` in which "cns" appears is an "ever treated" `id` -- one of their rows has `treatment`=1. The relevant criterion for "is an `outcome_category` counted or not?" is not the value of `treatment` in that row, it's whether *any* row for a given `id` has `treatment`=1. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting little problem. You can do:

```
select
  outcome_category,
  count(x.id) as count
from g
left join (
  select distinct id from g where treatment = 1
) x on x.id = g.id
where outcome_category is not null
group by outcome_category
order by count desc
```

Result:

```
 outcome_category  count 
 ----------------- ----- 
 cardiovascular    3     
 sensory           1     
 cns               1     
 metabolic         0
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8775102260f080c42813891351f7362a).

Answer (score 1):

This would appear to be just a simple aggregation,

```
select outcome_category, Count(*) count
from t
where treatment=1
group by outcome_category
order by Count(*) desc
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=266617abc39e7881aa51a26c53411ba0)

Comment: I realized that the table `g` I posted originally didn't have the particular difficulty I'm running into in my "real" data. Please see the new version in the main post; this maybe change your proposed solution. Thanks! (No worries if not of course.)

Comment: Ok, I did wonder. it was 00:45 local time when I posted so only just read your reply, but looks like you have a solution :)